# Turing machine M overwrites a non-blank char by B (Blank)?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

What are the implications of a non-blank character being over-written by a Turing machine M for the given input variable 'x'?

Intention of the question: I am trying to answer how the halting problem can be made decidable provided we have a TM which can say whether 'M' overwrites a non-blank character by Blank or not?

Comment: Remember that at the beginning of the computation, the tape (except for the input) is full of blanks. If the head never overwrites a blank, what do you think would happen?

Comment: @RanG. Its Looping and will never halt. I hope I caught the hint. Please correct me if I am incorrect

Comment: you are right. either it will halt, or it will loop (i.e., repeat the same configuration). Both events can be recognized by a machine (by a decider).